# How to write a scala function to accept arguments with two types?

Tags: scala, generics

I have two functions:

```
def capPredDouble(rawPred: Double): Double = {
  if (label == "1") {
    Math.min(1.0, rawPred)
  } else {
    Math.max(0, rawPred)
  }
}


def capPred(rawPred: Float): Float = {
  if (label == "1") {
    Math.min(1.0f, rawPred)
  } else {
    Math.max(0, rawPred)
  }
}
```

Is that possible to use polymorphism to make them one function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to work.

```
def capPred[N](rawPred :N)(implicit ev :Numeric[N]) :N =
  if (<some condition>) ev.min(ev.one,  rawPred)
  else                  ev.max(ev.zero, rawPred)
```

Comment: You don't actually need `ev.min` function. Just the `math.min(ev.one, rawPred)` works. same with max too.

Comment: We still need to define two implicit variables, right?

Comment: @whatsnext; No. Why would you need to do that? Have you tried the posted code? The `Numeric` type class covers types `Short`, `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, and `Double` (and perhaps a few more).

Comment: @jwvh, Yes, it works. Thanks! I was trying to understand the language better. Scala looks for members marked implicit. The compiler finds math.min(N,  N). Does that mean the scala function math.min is implicit? How does the compiler find ev.one and ev.zero?

Comment: The `scala.math` package is automatically in scope. No implicits required. When you call `capPred(8L)` the type parameter `N` is inferred to be type `Long`. If the method invocation doesn't include the 2nd parameter group then, because it is marked `implicit`, the compiler looks for an implicit instance of type `Numeric[Long]`. If one (and only one) is found then it is assigned to the local variable `ev`.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for the explanation! In this case, what is assigned to ev?

Comment: Go to the REPL and enter `implicitly[Numeric[Long]]` (using `Long` just as an example, `implicitly` is defined in the [Predef](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html)). The result, `res0: Numeric[Long] = scala.math.Numeric$LongIsIntegral$@3fc2959f`, tells us that it is an implicit in `math.Numeric` ([source file here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.7/src/library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L1)). The specific `implicit object` is at line 118 which extends `Ordering.LongOrdering` for `min()` and `max()` ops, and the `LongIsIntegral` trait for math ops.